# Meteor - SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

After running the `meteor` command, I have the following output:

```
=> Started MongoDB.
W20170502-15:50:05.028(2)? (STDERR)
/Users/user/Documents/App/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:5953
W20170502-15:50:05.074(2)? (STDERR) import {Mongo} from
'meteor/mongo'; W20170502-15:50:05.074(2)? (STDERR) ^^^^^^    
W20170502-15:50:05.075(2)? (STDERR)           
W20170502-15:50:05.075(2)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word W20170502-15:50:05.075(2)? (STDERR)     at
Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20170502-15:50:05.075(2)? (STDERR)     at
/Users/user/Documents/App/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:292:30
W20170502-15:50:05.075(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
```

In **app.js** file, line 5953, I have an import statement: `import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';`.

I tried to install ECMAScript with `meteor add ecmascript` but it doesn't work.

After trying to change the extensions from `.js` to `.ts`, it makes the server run on **localhost:3000**. But I get React errors.

Have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Where is this in your actual code? (not the bundled app.js file). Can you give any other context?

Comment: To help with debugging, can you (in this order) make sure `ecmascript` is installed, delete the `.meteor/local` directory, run `meteor` again to see if the problem still persists. Also, tell us your Meteor version.

Comment: Meteor version is 1.4.4.2. According to ./meteor/packages file ecmascript is installed `ecmascript@0.7.3   # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code`. But I can't find it in packages.json. Also I tried `add ecmascript-runtime` command, but after trying to update `meteor update` it says again:
that "`top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest
version available`".

Comment: try a `meteor reset` and run again then